# How to change spacing in the ACM conference template?

Tags: acm, author, author-number, affiliation, acmart

I am using ACM conference template. I cannot add spacing between the first author's e-mail and the second author's.

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\settopmatter{authorsperrow=3}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}

\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2018}
\acmYear{2018}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}

\acmConference[Woodstock '18]{Woodstock '18: ACM Symposium on Neural
  Gaze Detection}{June 03--05, 2018}{Woodstock, NY}
\acmBooktitle{Woodstock '18: ACM Symposium on Neural Gaze Detection,
  June 03--05, 2018, Woodstock, NY}
\acmPrice{15.00}
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-XXXX-X/18/06}

\begin{document}

\title{Paper ACM Template}

\author{Denis B. Oliveira}
\email{denis.oliveira@alunos.ifsuldeminas.edu.br}
\authornotemark[1]
\affiliation{
  \institution{Instituto Federal de Educação, Ciência e Tecnologia do Sul de Minas Gerais}
  \city{Poços de Caldas}
  \state{MG}
  \country{Brasil}
}

\author{Ricardo R. de Oliveira}
\email{ricardo.ramos@ifsuldeminas.edu.br}
\authornotemark[1]
\affiliation{
  \institution{Instituto Federal de Educação, Ciência e Tecnologia do Sul de Minas Gerais}
  \city{Poços de Caldas}
  \state{MG}
  \country{Brasil}
}

\author{Ricardo F. Vilela}
\email{ricardovilela@usp.br}
\authornotemark[2]
\affiliation{
  \institution{Universidade de São Paulo}
  \city{São Carlos}
  \state{SP}
  \country{Brasil}
}

\author{Victor H. S. C. Pinto}
\email{victor.pinto@zup.com.br}
\authornotemark[3]
\affiliation{
  \institution{Zup Innovation}
  \city{São Paulo}
  \state{SP}
  \country{Brasil}
}

\author{Roberto N. Ungarelli}
\email{roberto.ungarelli@oceanoazulti.com}
\authornotemark[4]
\affiliation{
  \institution{Oceano Azul TI}
  \city{Brasília}
  \state{DF}
  \country{Brasil}
}

\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{Denis B. Oliveira, et al.}

\begin{abstract}
\textbf{Background}: ...
\end{abstract}

\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
   <concept>
       <concept_id>10002944.10011123</concept_id>
       <concept_desc>General and reference~Cross-computing tools and techniques</concept_desc>
       <concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
       </concept>
   <concept>
       <concept_id>10002944.10011123.10011674</concept_id>
       <concept_desc>General and reference~Performance</concept_desc>
       <concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
       </concept>
 </ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{General and reference~Cross-computing tools and techniques}
\ccsdesc[500]{General and reference~Performance}

\keywords{Teste de desempenho, Plataforma como serviço, Sistema como serviço, Avaliação Experimental, Computação em nuvem}

\maketitle

\section{Introdução}
...

%\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
%\bibliography{references.bib}

\end{document}
\endinput
```

The result:

[image]

[acmart.cls file](https://gist.github.com/ricardousp/5fa39870ee6b78819136197c5b81e7e8#file-acmart-cls)

How do I include a space between the e-mails of the first author and the second author?

Comment: Are you using the template to submit a paper or for an other project ? If it is to submit a paper, I'd let it like that and let the editor manage the problem.

Comment: Hello @Bromind, thanks for your help! I will submit my paper to a conference. I was wondering if there is any simple way to solve this problem.

Comment: @ricardoramos, facin', facin', tem não. Mas tem uma gambiarra. Vê se serve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set to 2 authors per row:

```
\settopmatter{authorsperrow=2}
```

Now it fits.

#### Edit: Second Option

**An option is to put the two guys from the same institution in one cell, and perhaps abbreviate the huge institution name**

Up to you.

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\settopmatter{authorsperrow=2}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}

\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2018}
\acmYear{2018}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}

\acmConference[Woodstock '18]{Woodstock '18: ACM Symposium on Neural
  Gaze Detection}{June 03--05, 2018}{Woodstock, NY}
\acmBooktitle{Woodstock '18: ACM Symposium on Neural Gaze Detection,
  June 03--05, 2018, Woodstock, NY}
\acmPrice{15.00}
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-XXXX-X/18/06}

\begin{document}

\title{Paper ACM Template}

\author{Denis B. Oliveira}
\email{denis.oliveira@alunos.ifsuldeminas.edu.br}
\authornotemark[1]


\author{Ricardo R. de Oliveira}
\email{ricardo.ramos@ifsuldeminas.edu.br}
\authornotemark[1]
\affiliation{
  \institution{IFSULDEMINAS}
  \city{Poços de Caldas}
  \state{MG}
  \country{Brasil}
}

\author{Ricardo F. Vilela}
\email{ricardovilela@usp.br}
\authornotemark[2]
\affiliation{
  \institution{Universidade de São Paulo}
  \city{São Carlos}
  \state{SP}
  \country{Brasil}
}

\author{Victor H. S. C. Pinto}
\email{victor.pinto@zup.com.br}
\authornotemark[3]
\affiliation{
  \institution{Zup Innovation}
  \city{São Paulo}
  \state{SP}
  \country{Brasil}
}

\author{Roberto N. Ungarelli}
\email{roberto.ungarelli@oceanoazulti.com}
\authornotemark[4]
\affiliation{
  \institution{Oceano Azul TI}
  \city{Brasília}
  \state{DF}
  \country{Brasil}
}

\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{Denis B. Oliveira, et al.}

\begin{abstract}
\textbf{Background}: ...
\end{abstract}

\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
   <concept>
       <concept_id>10002944.10011123</concept_id>
       <concept_desc>General and reference~Cross-computing tools and techniques</concept_desc>
       <concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
       </concept>
   <concept>
       <concept_id>10002944.10011123.10011674</concept_id>
       <concept_desc>General and reference~Performance</concept_desc>
       <concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
       </concept>
 </ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{General and reference~Cross-computing tools and techniques}
\ccsdesc[500]{General and reference~Performance}

\keywords{Teste de desempenho, Plataforma como serviço, Sistema como serviço, Avaliação Experimental, Computação em nuvem}

\maketitle

\section{Introdução}
...

%\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
%\bibliography{references.bib}

\end{document}
```

#### Edit: Third Option

If you really want to do this, you can try setting

```
\makeatletter
%\def\@authorfont{\normalfont\small} %change font. don't do this.
%\def\@affiliationfont{\normalfont\small} %change font. don't do this.
\def\author@bx@sep{0pc}
\makeatother
```

before `\begin{document}`.

Then it fits. But be aware that all changes you make are liable to come to nought: if the editor wants a 2x2 setup with one author in the last line or a 2x2 option with authors of the same institution in the same cell, he will.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried this attempt before, but the result is not good. With this configuration I will have 2 authors per line and in the last line I will have only 1 author. The result is not good.

Comment: "The result is not good" is **very** subjective. You have an odd number. Of course there'll be only one author in the last line. These are space issues. The reason it feels worse than 2 is your personal feeling about numerology. Your options are: 1) Enlarge margins 2) Reduce font size 3) Break lines 4) "let the editor manage the problem" (including language issues) 5) Do what I said 6) a combination thereof.

Comment: Olá, Joseph, eu vi que você escreveu em português no outro comentário, então tomei a liberdade de escrever em português também. Mais uma vez muito obrigado mesmo por toda a sua ajuda! Me desculpe a forma como escrevi o meu inglês, talvez tenha soado de forma "grosseira", mas não foi essa a minha intenção.

Comment: Eu estava pensando em usar a quebra de linha (option 3) porém queria manter o `\settopmatter{authorsperrow=3}` setado em 3, se houvesse alguma forma de eu deixar os dois primeiros autores na linha de cima e fazer uma quebra com os outros 3 autores na linha de baixo ficaria perfeito e já marcaria esta questão como resolvida e além disso faço questão tb de dar um upvote para você por toda a sua ajuda! Grande abraço!

Comment: @ricardoramos see my updated answer.

Comment: Valeu @Joseph! Show de bola! Agora funcionou e deu tudo certo! Muito obrigado mesmo por toda a sua ajuda! Sobre o editor você tem razão sim... você é da Unicamp? Vi no seu perfil que você é de Campinas...

Comment: Apenas por curiosidade, teria como aumentar pouca coisa o espaçamento entre os dois primeiros autores na linha de cima? Seria muito complexo fazer isso?

Comment: @ricardoramos, Probably there's a way but I can't find it in the code. I wouldn't bother changing it (the editor will probably change it anyway).

Comment: Hello, @Joseph, no problem! Thank you very much for all your help, my friend!

Comment: @ricardoramos, disponha, estamos aqui pra isso.